# Comparing Express User with Mongoose Foreign Key

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

my mongoose model contains a foreign key for the model User.
If a put, post or delete request comes in, I would like to check if the primary ID of the currently authenticated user is the same as the foreign key.

If i log the id's they are exactly the same, but the code seems to differ. Can someone please tell me the correct way to go about this? Thanks in advance.

**Model**

```
mongoose.model(
  'MyModel',
  mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: true
    },
    ...
  })
)
```

**Express Route**

```
router.put('/models/:id', auth, (req, res, next) => {
  MyModel.findById(req.params.id, (err, model) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send({success: false, msg: 'Model not found'});
    if (req.user._id !== model.user) return res.status(500).send({sucess: false, msg: 'You did not create this model'});

    ...success...
  });
});
```

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it. The 'if(req.user._id !== model.user)' alwas returns true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the model, you are storing the user as `ObjectId` and whenever you match it with the user in,

`if (req.user._id !== model.user)`

it always returns true because `req.user._id` a string type and `model.user` has `ObjectId` type. It is like

```
if ("5b9b69933fc1de058a4086ed" !== ObjectId("5b9b69933fc1de058a4086ed")
```

You can compare them by converting the user id to an `ObjectId` type.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

if (!new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user._id).equals(model.user))
```

Comment: That was what I was thinking, but can you explain both why != doesn't work and how it will work?

Comment: This will help you. Follow the link http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html#equals

Comment: @AvcS How will the populate help him? OP just want to compare the stored Id in the user, not any data.